# In my Netbeans 8.1, <applet? Tag is not changing the size of the applet , just showing in the same standard size? What should I do?

Tags: java, netbeans, applet, japplet, netbeans-8.1

Please tell why I always getting the same size of the applet?

In my Netbeans 8.1, <applet? Tag is not changing the size of the applet , just showing in the same standard size?
What should I do?

**This is my code:**

```
package online.book.store;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*; 

/*
<applet code="Home_Page" width=300 height=800> </applet>
*/


class SampleFrame extends Frame { SampleFrame(String title) {
    
super(title);

MyWindowAdapter adapter = new MyWindowAdapter(this);

addWindowListener(adapter);

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

 
g.drawString("This is in frame window", 50, 90);

 

}

 

}

 

class MyWindowAdapter extends WindowAdapter { SampleFrame sampleFrame;

 

public MyWindowAdapter(SampleFrame sampleFrame) { this.sampleFrame = sampleFrame;
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stack Overflow, may you show the output that you receive?

Comment: Remove the blank lines between the code comment with the applet element, and the line starting `class SampleFrame extends Frame..` and also change that to `class SampleFrame extends Applet..`. Then move the code in the constructor into an `init()` method and specify the `@Override` marker.

Answer (score 0):

*define the* `getPreferredSize()` *in the frame*

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
  return( new Dimension( width, height ) );
}
```

Because `Applet` is deprecated I would not spend too much time on the subject.
*An* `Applet` *can't change the size of the frame in which it is executed, regardless of whether it is executed in a browser,* `Frame` *window or applet-viewer. You have to set the size of the* `Frame` *(see above). The* `<applet>` *tags are meanwhile unsupported in nearly every browser.*